# flowjs not recognizing import with @

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to import @aws/dynamo-data-mapper package from AWS. flow isn't recognizing the packages with @.

```
// @flow
import Joi from 'joi';
import { DataMapper } from '@aws/dynamo-data-mapper';
import DynamoDB from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';
```

Running flow is giving below error

Cannot resolve module @aws/dynamo-data-mapper.

```
 1│ // @flow
 2│ import Joi from 'joi';
 3│ import { DataMapper } from '@aws/dynamo-data-mapper';
 4│ import DynamoDB from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';
```

Wondering how to make flow recognize the packages that start with @.

Comment: Why do u want to use @ ? Isn’t this import { DataMapper } from 'aws/dynamo-data-mapper'; without @?

Comment: Nevermind..its an error on my side. I misspelled the package. correct package is @aws/dynamodb-data-mapper

Comment: @Think-Twice https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope